# There is given a countable set $A$. Prove that $(x+A)\cap A=\emptyset$ for some $x$

Tags: real-analysis

There is given a countable set $A\subset \Bbb{R}.$ Prove that there exists an $x\in R$ that $(x+A)\cap A=\emptyset$, where  $x+A=\{x+a: a\in A\}$.

Comment: is $A$ finite or only countable ?

Answer (score 2):

Let us enumerate the countable set $A$ as $A=\{a_0,a_1,\dots\}$, and let us define the countable set $X:=\{x_{m,n}\in\mathbb{R}:x_{m,n}=d(a_m,a_n)\}$. Since the set $X$ is countable (being in bijection with $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$), there is a real number $y$ not belonging to $X$. Then, $(y+A)\cap A=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the set of pairwise differences between elements of $A$. Since $A$ is countable, then this set of differences is countable (since it is the image of a function whose domain is $A \times A$ which is countable as the cartesian product of two countable sets is countable).

Since the set of differences is countable and $\mathbb{R}$ is not, then there exists an $x$ that is not in this set of differences. This $x$ yields the desired result since otherwise there would exists $a_1, a_2 \in A$ such that $x+a_1 = a_2$ implying $x = a_2-a_1$, a difference between two elements in $A$ which we know $x$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

We suppose that $A$ is countable. Suppose that : $$\forall x \in \Bbb R \quad (x+A)\cap A \neq  \emptyset$$
Then $$(\forall x \in \Bbb R)(\exists a \in A) \quad x \in A-a$$
then : $$\Bbb R=\bigcup_{a \in A} (A-a)$$
Since $A$ is countable, we get $\Bbb R$ as coutable union of countable sets, then $\Bbb R$ would be   countable, this is false.